# What am I getting wrong here?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to build a simple "game" that will teach multiplication to my son. The script is below as a link to the screenshot.

Issue:

The multiplication does not seem to work. x1*x2 returns `#NUM!`. When I checked the spreadsheet, the numbers are not a text string.

What am I getting wrong here?

```
function multiplicationgame() {



  var GameSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Multiplication");



  var x1 = GameSheet.getRange("A2");
  var x2 = GameSheet.getRange("B2");




  // for generating a random number Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  x1.setValue(Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1));
  x2.setValue(Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1));


  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.prompt('Enter Answer Here:');

  // creates a temp halt in speardsheet execution till the answer is entered
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  var Answer = GameSheet.getRange("A7").getValue();


  var x3 = GameSheet.getRange("B7");


  if (Answer == x1*x2) (x3.setValue('Thats correct! Well done'));
  else (x3.setValue('Thats wrong! Better luck next time'))


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Multiplication process restored.

You were using the range as a value.

```
function multiplicationgame() {
  var GameSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet71");
  var x1 = GameSheet.getRange("A2");
  var x2 = GameSheet.getRange("B2");
  var x3 = GameSheet.getRange("A7");
  var x4=GameSheet.getRange("B7");

  // for generating a random number Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  var m1=Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  var m2=Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  x1.setValue(m1);
  x2.setValue(m2);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.prompt('Multiplication', Utilities.formatString('%s x %s = ?',m1,m2 ), ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  // creates a temp halt in speardsheet execution till the answer is entered
  x3.setValue(response.getResponseText());
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var Answer = GameSheet.getRange("A7").getValue();

  if (Answer == m1*m2) {
    x4.setValue('Thats correct! Well done');
  }else{
    x4.setValue('Thats wrong! Better luck next time');
  }
}
```

Comment: Super! Thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome.  Have a great day.  I changed some of your data display because it's handy to be able to see intermediate answers when you're debugging code.